# Interpret timestamp fields in Spark while reading json

Tags: json, apache-spark, timestamp

I am trying to read a pretty printed json which has time fields in it. I want to interpret the timestamps columns as timestamp fields while reading the json itself. However, it's still reading them as string when I `printSchema`

E.g. 
Input json file -

```
[{
    "time_field" : "2017-09-30 04:53:39.412496Z"
}]
```

Code -

```
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'").json('path_to_json_file')
```

Output of `df.printSchema()` -

```
root
 |-- time_field: string (nullable = true)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

My own experience with option `timestampFormat` is that it doesn't quite work as advertised.  I would simply read the time fields as strings and use `to_timestamp` to do the conversion, as shown below (with slightly generalized sample input):

```
# /path/to/jsonfile
[{
    "id": 101, "time_field": "2017-09-30 04:53:39.412496Z"
},
{
    "id": 102, "time_field": "2017-10-01 01:23:45.123456Z"
}]
```

In Python:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json("/path/to/jsonfile")

df = df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp("time_field"))

df.show(2, False)
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
|id |time_field                 |timestamp          |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
|101|2017-09-30 04:53:39.412496Z|2017-09-30 04:53:39|
|102|2017-10-01 01:23:45.123456Z|2017-10-01 01:23:45|
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- time_field: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

In Scala:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json("/path/to/jsonfile")

df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp($"time_field"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's bug in Spark version 2.4.0 [Issues SPARK-26325](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26325)

For Spark Version 2.4.4

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType

//String to timestamps
val df = Seq(("2019-07-01 12:01:19.000"),
  ("2019-06-24 12:01:19.000"),
  ("2019-11-16 16:44:55.406"),
  ("2019-11-16 16:50:59.406")).toDF("input_timestamp")

val df_mod = df.select($"input_timestamp".cast(TimestampType))

df_mod.printSchema
```

Output

```
root
 |-- input_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: yeah, I'm the one who logged it as a bug there!